# Encolar subida de archivos con php para no execer el upload_max_filesize topado a 2mb

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy desarrollando un plugin en wordpress para subir un fichero zip y descomprimirlo en una carpeta. En local todo funciona perfecto porque mi php.ini esta topado a 20mb pero en el server de producción es de solo 2mb y no hay forma de modificar dicho parámetro.

Es posible encolar los archivos uno a uno para poder evitar la restriccón de upload_max_filesize ?

Se puede configruar del lado de php o seria desde el lado del cliente?

He intentado con estas directivas de configuración pero no tienen efecto, tampoco devuelven error.

```
ini_set("upload_max_size" , "20M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "20M"); 
ini_set("memory_limit", "1500M");
```

Comment: Creo que se puede modificar los parámetros del server con un archivo `.htaccess`, pero no recuerdo las reglas en este momento... Te dejo la inquietud para que la consultes.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. No me esta permitido modificar dichos parámetros por ello estoy viendo la forma de como sortear dicha limitante.

Answer (score 0):

Para tu pregunta:

> Es posible encolar los archivos uno a uno para poder evitar la restriccón de upload_max_filesize?

Claro que se puede, teniendo acceso `FTP`, creas la carpeta `wp-content/plugins/tu_plugin` y cargas en ella los archivos del plugin, uno a uno.

> Se puede configruar del lado de php o seria desde el lado del cliente?

Siempre la configuración es del lado del servidor. El cliente no tiene nada que hacer con `php` solo recibe el html generado.

Hay algunas configuraciones que se pueden y otras que no se pueden realizar a través de `ini_set`. En particular según el manual php los [parámetros que buscas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) son del modo `PHP_INI_PERDIR` [lo que significa](https://www.php.net/manual/es/configuration.changes.modes.php) que pueden ser modificados en `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` o `.user.ini`

Intenta en el archivo `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

O crea un archivo `.user.ini` en la raíz de tu sitio.

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```